# Product of ring epimorphisms (right-cancellative in Ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, infinite-product

Given a family of ring epimorphisms
$$ \varphi_i\colon R_i \to S_i $$

is the unique ring morphism

$$ \varphi \colon R \to S $$
with $R=\prod_i R_i$, $S=\prod_i S_i$ and $\pi^S_i \circ \varphi = \varphi_i \circ \pi^R_i $ an epimorphism? The $\pi$ denote the projections of the products.

Comment: I think I can prove this for finite products; I suspect it's not true for infinite products. Are you more interested in the infinite case?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was just curious about it and don't know much about rings, but I had the infinite case in mind. Now I saw on Stacks Project that there is the characterization that $S\otimes_R S \to S$ must be an iso. So taking $$ \prod S_i \otimes_{\prod R_i} \prod S_i \to \prod (S_i \otimes_{R_i} S_i),\ (s_i)_i\otimes(s'_i)_i \mapsto (s_i\otimes s'_i)_i  $$
should yield an iso in the finite case. But in the infinite case the number of summands on the RHS is not bounded. Could a prove of the finite case be like this?

Comment: Yes, that's one approach, although if you were asking about commutative rings you should specify this; I think epimorphisms in noncommutative rings behave differently (the tensor product is replaced in the free product in your characterization).